# Is there an alternative to cflush in gem5?

Tags: gem5

In the old version of gem5 (commit: 38a1e23), the cflush command is not implemented? Is there a command similar to cflush for clearing cache lines? I want to use gem5 to simulate spectre attack (a side channel attack). Because I have made some changes on gem5, I can't directly switch to the new version.